# How to stop download Sitecore media items (png)?

Tags: media-library

When I click on Sitecore items that have an image field with png image uploaded in it, pop-up appears to download the image.
How can I stop the pop-up from appearing? even though I put the force download to false and this issue only appears on the firefox browser.

```
<mediaType name="png file" extensions="png">
          <mimeType>application/png</mimeType>
          <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
        </mediaType>
```

[image]

Comment: make sure you don't have any browser extension installed on your browser, try by disabling all the enable extensions in browsers.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat disabled all the extensions but the issue still showing
this issue appears on all devices not just one.